# how can i delete 0 at the first of number with python

Tags: python, integer

Please i need to delete all 0 in the beginning of numbre even the type of variable is char like :

```
Number = "0000386489"

"0000386489"  --->>  386489
```

or having an integer numbre with 0 at first

Comment: Do you want the result to be the integer `386489` or the string `'386489'`?

Comment: `int(Number )` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this with several ways.

1. Using int and str casting operations:

   `txt_number = "00036"; txt_number = str(int(txt_number))`

However, this will only work on integer numbers and may not be the best method for floating numbers.

2. Another way is to use lstrip operation on the string directly.

   `txt_number = "0036".lstrip("0")`

Answer (score 2):

Python automatically removes leading zeros for integers, as for strings, you can just convert them to integers:

```
a = "0000123"
print(a) ----> 0000123
print(int(a)) ----> 123
```

If you want the output to be a string, you can convert it again to string using `str` method.